# Mustang dev board Ubuntu installation

Tags: 14.04, boot, system-installation, arm

We got a Mustang development board (applied micro) and I’m trying to install Ubuntu on it based on this page instruction: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/Server/Install/Mustang

I've did everything mentioned on above and finished installation but when I reset the board to boot, I get the following error:

```
Gave up waiting for root device.  Common problems:                              
 - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)                                                
   - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)                        
   - Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)                    
 - Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)                                 
ALERT!  /dev/disk/by-uuid/1834a3cd-2209-46c1-b750-a2cda6c25445 does not exist.!
BusyBox v1.21.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.21.0-1ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)                 
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.                                   

(initramfs)
```

I've found this error be very common for Ubuntu 14.04 installation and upgrade, and there are a lot of solutions. But none of them worked for me since most of them need live CD or grub and etc. The board has `uboot` as its boot loader.

Comment: Can you share the U-boot configuration environment? If you have no way of saving it, how about a high-res picture? pause the bootloader by pressing any key during the timeout window, then issue the 'printenv' command.